# TaxCloud: Lookup Sales Tax Throws 409

Tags: node.js, npm

I used the Taxcloud **POST API** https://api.taxcloud.com/1.0/TaxCloud/Lookup for Lookup Sales Tax using **request** NPM package. I just used **uuid** NPM package to generate the unique identifier for **customerID, ItemID, cartID** of my request object.
[Here is the documentation about TaxCloud where I referred](https://dev.taxcloud.com/guides/how-to-lookup-sales-tax-due).

> **My Request Object:**

{ apiLoginID: 'XXXXXXXXX',
  apiKey: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  customerID: '24d1d040-8673-4ecf-94e8-8512d5e8b022',
  deliveredBySeller: false,
  cartID: 'b974084e-1529-403b-afac-1097fe171faa',
  destination: 
   { Address1: '15083 US 19 S',
     City: 'THOMASVILLE',
     State: 'GA',
     Zip5: '31792',
     Zip4: '' },
  origin: 
   { Address1: '262 Rio Cir',
     City: 'DECATUR',
     State: 'GA',
     Zip5: '30030',
     Zip4: '' },
  cartItems: 
   [ { Qty: 1,
       Price: 30,
       TIC: 40030,
       ItemID: 'a7d5fe75-62f0-4d62-9381-39ea6191bbd8',
       Index: 0 } ] }

> **Error Response:**

{ CartID: null,
  CartItemsResponse: [],
  ResponseType: 0,
  Messages: 
   [ { ResponseType: 0,
       Message: 'An error has occurred proessing your request.  Please contact TaxCloud (code:409)' } ] }

Comment: *"Please contact TaxCloud"*. StackOverflow != TaxCloud.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, Thanks for your comment:) I have submitted an request to the TaxCloud support center about this issue, I thought any one of the Stackoverflow users may faced such kind of issue. Anyhow I need a solution to overcome this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not valid JSON. All object parameter names need to be quoted as well, for example:

```
{apiLoginID: "XXXXXXXXX"}
```

should be:

```
{"apiLoginID": "XXXXXXXXX"}
```